# ErrorDocument doesn't seem to be working in my .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, errordocument

Can anyone advise please?  I'd like to have the default page for visitors to my site as being index.php and for all non-existent pages the visitor should see errordoc.php

So I've put this in the .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errordoc.php

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite\.org\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.org.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Unfortunately everything is going to index.php, including errors.  I've tried asking my friend Google but it's his day off today!

Comment: Strange, it looks fine. Does it work if you remove the rewrite part?

Comment: Thanks Pekka, I've removed the last Rewrite Rule and it's working just fine now.

Comment: And left everything else in place? LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last rule will catch all requests that cannot be mapped onto existing files (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`) or existing directories (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`). That’s why the error document will not be served.

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 incompatible sections in this file. choose one
leave either only first line or only the rest of the file. But not both.

Bottom three lines tells web-server to direct all non-existent pages to the index.php, not to errordoc.php